# Can't store Date.Utcnow in vb.net 2012

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I just wondering, why I can't store the simplest code that you can use to get the time and date to begin with.

I'm using Visual Basic 2012 and just simply add Service-based database (.mdf) on my project.

I already add table ( tblTime ) and created the column ( Time ) which is set to data type 'datetime'

But every time I try to store the date ( using Date.Utcnow ) I keep getting this error

"The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

I tried to stop the program and tried to directly put the value of ( Date.Utcnow ) into the table and it works.

I honestly don't know what I'm missing here. I know its so damn easy for you guys to know the problem. But yeah' not for me I guess.

Here's my code :

```
    con.Open()
    With cmd
        .Connection = con
        .CommandText = "Insert into tblTime(Time) values('" & Date.UtcNow & "')"
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
    End With
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
```

Comment: You are passing a string not a datetime. It is time to learn how to use parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a string between the single quotes. This code converts automatically a DateTime variable to a string accordingly to your default locale conversion schema, then it concatenates everything together and pass everything to the database. Now the database engine is forced to convert back that string to a DateTime and this is where it fails. It cannot make sense of your string as a Date and rejects the command.

Instead with parameters you have the possibility to pass directly the DateTime value and the database doesn't need to convert anything.

```
con.Open()
With cmd
    .Connection = con
    .CommandText = "Insert into tblTime([Time]) values(@time)"
    .Parameters.Add("@time", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Date.UtcNow
    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
End With
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```

In this code the command text doesn't contain a conversion in string of your value but just a parameter placeholder. The actual value is passed through the  parameter of the correct datatype directly to the database engine and parser, so there is no need to convert a string back to a datetime

Also note that a field named **Time** is a problem because it is a possible keyword for the database engine. Better change that name or if you want to use it then enclose it between square brackets

Comment: Hello Steve,

Thank you for helping me, seems I getting the problem now and you're right maybe it's time to use parameters.


So I tried the codes and changed the name of my field. The thing is the code runs well, but seems no value has been inserted on field. I've look into the tables data  it is totally "Null" value. Seems nothing changed. 
(Starting to think software problem).

Comment: No quotes around a parameter. Look at my code. There is no point in adding quotes because this is just a placeholder for the value. If you put quotes you transform the placeholder in a literal text and we are back to square one. Trying to insert a string inside a datetime column

Comment: If you don't see updates and there is no exception then it is a well know situation. Happens a lot when there is a difference between your app connectionstring and the server explorer window connection string. Or if you have **DataDirectory** substitution string applied to your MDF file in a desktop application. Essentially you are searching your insert in the wrong database

Comment: Hello Steve, Thank you so much. Problem solved! :) Your code is perfectly fine. I just changed my connection string and it works and stored data :)  I wish I could be as good as you someday :) I'll be hanging here a lot from now on, and will consider parameters. I know there's so much more to learn. But yeah, this will be my first step :) Cheers bro! :)

Comment: Woah, so that how its done! Thanks for the link! Too much skip I think haha.